# Date formatting using strptime function in R

Tags: r, datetime, rstudio, strptime

I have loaded the Arbuthnot set from R

```
data('arbuthnot')
arbuthnot<-data.frame(arbuthnot)
```

Now the year variable in this data set is an integer variable

```
str(arbuthnot)
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year : int  1629 1630 1631 1632 1633 1634 1635 1636 1637 1638 ...
 $ boys : int  5218 4858 4422 4994 5158 5035 5106 4917 4703 5359 ...
 $ girls: int  4683 4457 4102 4590 4839 4820 4928 4605 4457 4952 ...
```

So to convert it into a Date object, I do the following

```
arbuthnot$year<-strptime(arbuthnot$year,'%Y')
str(arbuthnot)
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year : POSIXlt, format: "1629-03-28" "1630-03-28" "1631-03-28" "1632-03-28" ...
 $ boys : int  5218 4858 4422 4994 5158 5035 5106 4917 4703 5359 ...
 $ girls: int  4683 4457 4102 4590 4839 4820 4928 4605 4457 4952 ...
```

I don't want R to automatically add the date and month in the year variable. I instead want it to only hold the year variable. So ideally I want a run of str(arbuthnot) to look like this.

```
str(arbuthnot)
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ year : POSIXlt, format: "1629" "1630" "1631" "1632" ...
 $ boys : int  5218 4858 4422 4994 5158 5035 5106 4917 4703 5359 ...
 $ girls: int  4683 4457 4102 4590 4839 4820 4928 4605 4457 4952 ...
```

Why does R automatically add the current month and date(Today is the 28th of March) and what can I do to stop this?

Comment: `year` already has the year information. What else do you expect?

Comment: You mean you want the month and day to be 01-01?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
strftime("1629-03-28", format= '%Y', usetz = FALSE)
[1] "1629"
```

Comment: The following error occurs : 
> arbuthnot$year<-strftime(arbuthnot$year,'%Y',usetz = FALSE)

Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: Well, I get the same error starting with int(eger) data rather than character.